# Objective C method removeFromSuperview causes message being sent to deallocated object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, dealloc

I'm having an issue when calling removeFromSuperview in a View object. The allocation history (according to instruments) is the following:

myView alloc -> myView 1

addSubview:myview -> myView 2

myView release -> myView 1

myView removeFromSuperview -> myView 0

myView dealloc -> myView -1 (invoked by removeFromSuperview)

I understand that the dealloc method is called because the reference count reaches 0. However, I don't understand why it decreases the reference count by one, causing the message being sent to deallocated method.

Also, I can only detect it using instruments. Using xcode it doesn't crash.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you manually invoke the last `myView dealloc` or is it invoked by `removeFromSuperview`?

Comment: Is being invoked by removeFromSuperview.

Comment: Did you try your app without releasing myView first so its count is still 2? I think `removeFromSuperview` will automatically take care of the additional `alloc`.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I checked with instruments and it leaks. The count stays in +1

Comment: What happens if you change the order to `alloc`, `addSubview`, `removeFromSuperview` `release`? It's possible that `removeFromSuperview` does the releasing part dynamically.

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I don't really understand why. So, if in the dealloc method I do: [myView release]; instead of [self.myView release]; it works fine. Do you have any explanation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another really easy way to find reference count issues with Xcode is to use Analyze, the compiler is now smart enough to implement automatic reference counting, so it is also smart enough to find problems with reference counting.

Comment: +1 heh, yeah that too =) i'd assumed that the obvious had already been done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to sort this issue out is typically:

- running the program in instruments **with reference count recording enabled**
- reproduce the issue
- execution will halt
- then you analyze the reference count history and find the improper decrement in the history

once you get the hang of it, locating zombies takes about 2 minutes.